# posix_fallocate writes 1 byte at a time at 4K intervals, causing my fuse over NFS implementation to be very slow

Tags: linux, filesystems, posix, fuse

I have a fuse module that re-exports an NFS share.  Applications like fio that call posix_fallocate end up calling my fuse write function with one byte writes at a spread of 4K.  This in turn results into one byte RPC calls over NFS making the performance very slow.

How do I advertise to the application via fuse that I can handle the fallocate directly and it should not resort to single byte writes?

Comment: Does your fuse filesystem not implement the fallocate call?

Answer (score 1):

what you need is:
do not let your fuse return `EOPNOTSUPP`  upon the `posix_fallocate` calling.

I strace the posix_fallocate  on linux with an NFS volume mounted.
It turns out that linux's posix_fallocate implementation does hard jobs of writing 1 byte to each block when it encounter the EOPNOTSUPP.

The line below shows part of the strace outputed:

```
fallocate(3, 0, 0, 8589934592)          = -1 EOPNOTSUPP (Operation not   supported)
pwrite(3, "\0", 1, 1048575)             = 1
pwrite(3, "\0", 1, 2097151)             = 1
pwrite(3, "\0", 1, 3145727)             = 1*
.....
```

Comment: Glibc's `posix_fallocate` slowly emulating preallocation when the filesystem can't do `fallocate` on Linux is a well known thing unfortunately: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23508718/7836056 .