# How to make NFS support posix_fallocate?

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, nfs

My full text search engine store indexed data on NFS store.
Due to the frequently read/write ioes,I want to preallocate huge continuous disk space for each table file and so resort to posix_fallocate.
On an NFS volume,My little demo failed  with "EOPNOTSUPP" responsed to posix_fallocate.
Does NFS protocal/specification include the posix_fallocate scenario?

Comment: fallocate gives the filesystem a chance, to allocate the space more efficiently than just writing zeroes to the file. If the underlying filesystem does not support it, the best you can do is to open the file and write a number of zero bytes up to the desired filesize. This will in most cases not be more inefficient than using `fallocate()`.

Comment: What version of NFS?  What OS version(s) are you running for your NFS client and server?  Can you post your code? The discussions from a [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=posix_fallocate+linux+nfs) seem to indicate glibc should emulate `posix_fallocate()` over NFS, but the emulation appears to have some bugs.

Answer (score 2):

(While the title of the question mentions `posix_fallocate` the [definition of `posix_fallocate` means `EOPNOTSUPP` is not an error code it will return](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_fallocate.html). It seems highly likely the questioner was actually using [`fallocate` on Linux as that CAN return `EOPNOTSUPP`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html#ERRORS))

NFS *can* support `fallocate` on Linux (http://wiki.linux-nfs.org/wiki/index.php/Fallocate ) but:

1. Your client and server have to be using NFS 4.2 or later.
2. An NFS 4.2+ server doesn't HAVE to implement fallocate - it's optional (see the posting [Re: [PATCH 4/4] Remove broken posix_fallocate, posix_falllocate64 fallback code [BZ#15661]](https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2015-05/msg00062.html) in a libc-alpha mailing list thread]).

Re `posix_fallocate`, you can [never know whether a Linux glibc `posix_fallocate` call was real or emulated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23508718/2732969) without careful observation or manual checking beforehand (e.g. by making a platform native `fallocate` call and checking if it failed or wasn't supported) and if you've done the native call why did you need the `posix_fallocate` call?. Further, different platforms have a different  call for a native `fallocate` (or completely lack it) so if portability to non-Linux platforms is a concern you will need to write the appropriate native `fallocate` wrappers for each platform. If you *have* to do pre-allocation even when what's below you doesn't have a supported call for it, you will have to fall back to doing it by hand (e.g. via nice chunky writes or hacks like glibc's `posix_fallocate`...).

Note: When it is possible to do a real pre-allocation (e.g. via `fallocate`) it can be DRAMATICALLY faster than having to do full writes because the filesystem can fulfill it by just setting appropriate metadata.