# How to create files which share an extent?

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, extent

The Linux programmer's manual manpage [fallocate(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html) states:

> If the `FALLOC_FL_UNSHARE` flag is specified in *mode*, shared file data extents will be made private to the file to guarantee that a subsequent write will not fail due to lack of space. Typically, this will be done by performing a copy-on-write operation on all shared data in the file. This flag may not be supported by all filesystems.

That's cool, but… **How do I create shared file data extents in the first place**?

Comment: Also see the [`fallocate (2)` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html) and [fallocate vs posix_fallocate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14063046/608639) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shared data extents are created when the underlying filesystem supports **reflinks** (example: XFS and BTRFS) and you perform a `cp` with the `--reflink` flag or use the [ioctl_ficlonerange(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_ficlonerange.2.html) syscall.

Looking at the kernel code, I see `FALLOC_FL_UNSHARE_RANGE` being handled only in case of XFS, so maybe this flag to fallocate works only on XFS as of now.